# Where is ADODB 2.8 on Server 2008 / Vista?

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, windows-server-2008, adodb

I've been developing a C# project that references the ADODB 2.8 COM on a Windows 2005 machine.  (No I'm not using it for data access I need it because CDO needs returns ADODB.Streams).

Now I've tried opening this solution on a Server 2008 box but I'm told ADOB 2.8 is missing and sure enough there aren't any ADODB items in the COM references list and the /programs files/Common Files/microsoft shared/ folder is missing the ado folder.

Now I understand that Vista / Server 2008 has Windows DAC 6.0 which is what MDAC is now called, so I'm retisent to just go ahead and install MDAC.

Anyone else come across or solved this? Is there another place I can get hold of an interop for ADODB.Stream?  Should I be using MDAC 2.8?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[The documentation for DAC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms692877(VS.85).aspx) states (emphasis mine):

> Windows DAC includes some changes to work with Windows Vista, but is **almost** entirely functionally equivalent to MDAC 2.8.

It's because of that "almost" which makes me use MDAC 2.8 when I need to use ADO 2.8, not Windows DAC.

For those interested you can [download MDAC 2.8](http://www.microsoft.com/download/en/details.aspx?id=5793).